# Rails: ajax not rendering div with returned partial view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I am trying to `prepend` a partial view returned by an ajax request to a div content. I have been trying for quite some time now, but it does not seem to want to work.

Here is my javascript (jquery) code:

```
$("#new_post_form").bind "ajax:success", (event, data, xhr) ->
  $("#feed").prepend(data)
```

My controller will return a partial view when a post is created:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.js   { render :partial => "posts/post", :locals => {:post => @post}}
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Not sure why the data does not get added to the #feed. I believe the data is an object rather than a html string?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

*Extra:*
Form that calls ajax

```
=simple_form_for(@post, :method => "post", :remote => true, :id => "new_post_form") do |f|
  =f.error_notification
  =f.text_area :description, :id => "post_box", :class => "span12"
  %br
  %div{:id=>"post_box_buttons"}
    .input-append
      =f.select("location_id", @college.locations.collect {|r| [ r.name, r.id ] }, { :include_blank => false })
      =f.button :submit, :value => "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

Answer (score 0):

`simple_form_for` doesn't add your desired `id` that way. You need:

`=simple_form_for(@post, :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => {id: 'new_post_form'}) do |f|`